# Force build.phonegap export app with Android 4

Tags: android, cordova

Are there any way to force [build.phonegap](http://build.phonegap.com) export app with Android O.S Version 4.0.1 or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config.xml can be configured with minimum and maximum SDK versions:

http://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

See: "Minimum and Maximum SDK Version" in "Android Specific"

ie:

`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />`